# Why does this gpg command in a script behave differently when it's pasted into a shell?

Tags: bash

Here is a script which symmetrically encrypts/decrypts a file with two different symmetric ciphers in sequence.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Arguments: enc|dec filename"
    exit
fi

E="gpg -o - --symmetric --cipher-algo"
D="gpg -o - --decrypt"
ERR="2>/dev/null"

if [ "$1" = "enc" ]; then
    $E AES $2 | $E TWOFISH -
elif [ "$1" = "dec" ]; then
    $D $2 ${ERR} | $D - ${ERR}
else
    echo "Arguments: enc|dec filename"
    exit
fi
```

When I run `./doublecrypt dec /tmp/test.encrypted` I get the errors

```
usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]
usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]
```

If I change the line

```
$D $2 ${ERR} | $D - ${ERR}
```

to

```
echo "$D $2 ${ERR} | $D - ${ERR}"
```

It prints

```
gpg -o - --decrypt /tmp/xenc 2>/dev/null | gpg -o - --decrypt - 2>/dev/null
```

If I copy-paste this into bash, it runs correctly.

So why doesn't it work if I remove the `echo` and let the bash script evaluate it directly, as in the original form?

I am running Ubuntu Saucy and bash is my shell.

Comment: Probably the environment the script is running is different.  Often what is forgotten is that when the script is triggered via cron or called from a web app etc... there is no logged in user.  Which means variables like PATH that are set via login files don't exist.

Comment: I'm running the script and the copy-pasted line from the same shell.

Comment: not exactly.. the script runs in it's own shell even when started from a command prompt.  the problems that occur because of this are often related to what whatever is set during login using .bash_profile.   This case is a little different tho because normally you would see something like `gpg: not found` rather than a specific parameter failing, unless there is more than one gpg on your machine and they are being found differently along search PATHs that are differnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: you're running into trouble because of the order in which the shell parses various elements of command lines; specifically, it expands variable references (like `${ERR}`) about halfway through the process -- after it's already dealt with things like quotes and escapes and redirects. In your case, it's the redirects part that matters: by the time the shell expands `${ERR}` into `2>/dev/null`, it's already looked for redirects and not found any, so it just treats `2>/dev/null` as an argument to the command, and then `gpg` rejects that as making no sense.

Basically, storing commands (or command elements) in variables is the wrong way to do it. Variables are for data, not executable code. In this case, you'd be far better off using functions instead:

```
e() {
    gpg -o - --symmetric --cipher-algo "$@"
}
d() {
    gpg -o - --decrypt "$@" 2>/dev/null
}

if [ "$1" = "enc" ]; then
    e AES "$2" | e TWOFISH -
elif [ "$1" = "dec" ]; then
    d "$2" | d -
else
    echo "Arguments: enc|dec filename"
    exit
fi
```

Note that I also enclosed `$2` in double-quotes, to prevent its value from being subjected to the second half of the shell parsing process.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a totally separate problem, but this version seems to hang gpg. Have you actually tried runing it?

Comment: @spraff: I don't have gpg installed, so I can't test it, but I think I see the problem. `e` needs to take two arguments (the cipher and the filename), but it was only passing one of them on to `gpg`. I suspect that without a filename, `gpg` was trying to read from stdin, and hanging because there was nothing there. I changed `e` to use `"$@"` to pass all of its arguments on to `gpg` (and made the same change in `d`, though it shouldn't matter). This should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I used `$@` instead of `"$@"`, won't your way pass both arguments as one token?

Comment: @spraff: Use the double-quotes; the shell handles `"$@"` specially, and will treat each argument as a separate word in the expansion (`"$*"` does what you're thinking of -- see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)). If you use `$@` unquoted, the shell will perform the second half of the parsing process (word splitting and wildcard expansion) on each argument before passing it on to the function, which can cause weird bugs if your filenames have any funny characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$D $2 ${ERR} | $D - ${ERR}` to:

```
$( $D $2 ${ERR} | $D - ${ERR} )
```

Also, use the full path to your `gpg` program, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg
```

Comment: No difference..